# Sum JSON data in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter

I am from a web background and am trying to learn flutter, I am building a cart and I will like to sum all the price based on what the user has in the cart, am using a PHP backend.
Below is my method that fetches the database

```
    final String apiURL = 'mydomain/fetchcart.php';
     Future<List<ProductData>> fetchcart() async {
      var data = {'id': int.parse(id)};
      var response = await http.post(apiURL, body: json.encode(data));
       if (response.statusCode == 200) {
       final items = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
       List<ProductData> studentList = items.map<ProductData>((json) {
         return ProductData.fromJson(json);
         }).toList();
       return studentList;
      } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load data from Server.');
   }
 }
```

Am using a futurebuilder to pass it to a widget, but I to want sum the item price

```
        FutureBuilder<List<ProductData>>(
                  future: fetchcart(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData)
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                    return cartItems(
                        snapshot.data[index].pid,
                        snapshot.data[index].pName,
                        snapshot.data[index].pSellingPrice,
                        snapshot.data[index].pImage);
                  },
                );
              }),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the `pSellingPrice` is the price, before returning the `studentList` from your future builder use a foreach loop to get the total.

first declare a variable outside the `fetchcart()` in a suitable data type. I will use a double.

> `double total = 0;`

after List Generation,

> ```
> studentList.forEach((val){
>     total += val.pSellingPrice;
> });
> ```

you may need to call setState dependeing on your Ui.

Comment: Thanks alot, it worked but when I added   cartList.forEach((val) {
        total += val.pSellingPrice;
        setState(() {
           total += val.pSellingPrice;
        });
      });      it keeps add it almost every seconds, it starts with the current summation, then it doubles almost every seconds e.g if it evaluates to 1000, it doubles to 2000,4000, automatically

Comment: set the total to 0 before the list generation. it seems your future builder is called continuedly. is it called from initState?

Comment: No, am calling the future builder in the scaffold and the `total ` is declared before the method `fetchcart()', Here is a link to the dart file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GaqCJbupF7uxNF2g3QYH-BQU59kS0K5X/view?usp=sharing